# Closure Linter Windows Python 3.6 "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Tags: python, windows, google-closure-linter

I am unable to run Google Closure Linter on Windows 10 with Python 3.6. I get the following error with `gjslint`

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> gjslint
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\gjslint-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('closure-linter==2.3.19', 'console_scripts', 'gjslint')()
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 565, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2631, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2291, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2297, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\closure_linter\gjslint.py", line 176
    print '%s: %d' % (path, len(path_errors))
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace it to

```
print ('%s: %d' % (path, len(path_errors)))
```

In Python 2, print is a statement but in in Python 3, print() is a function
Also I recommend use formatting like `print ('{0}: {1}'.format (path, len(path_errors)))`